# Can't use soap on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, ksoap2

I've imported the 2.1.2 jar file to my library, however the issue is that I get this exception:

> `org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope`: Error!: Missing stack map in:  at
>   label: 30

I've tried to preverify the jar, but when I open the preverify exe, it just opens for a millisecond and immediately closes. Any way around this?

Comment: Not familiar with that jar but I find when using third party jars instead of using the jar itself add the source of the jar to your project and work from that. It may prove easier trying to find the problem.

Comment: I've added the jar to my library, and this is the problem I get.

Comment: What jar are you familiar with for Blackberry that supports soap?

Comment: Have never used soap with Blackberry, buut have had issues trying to intergrate third party jars into blackberry apps. Was just trying to point out it may be easier to debug the problem with the source attached.

Comment: Ok thanks mate. I think it might be a classpath or verification problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [BlackBerry Core Development Guide contains an example](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/Preverify_a_BlackBerry_Java_Application_512512_11.jsp).

At the command prompt, type:

```
preverify.exe [-d] output -classpath directory input; directory
```

Answer (score 2):

BlackBerry devices use j2me, so cannot make use of standard java libraries.  Are you using the [j2me version of ksoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksoap2/files/ksoap2/2.1.2/), and not the j2se version?

Answer (score 1):

It was a verification issues, I needed to use verify.exe to verify the JAR and then attach that to the library. Use the command line to access (change directory to) the folder where verify.exe (it's in eclipse) is and the go verify.exe -classpath [reference the net_rim jar here] [reference your jar here]